# No module named 'sklearn' after I installed it

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn import tree
```

I installed scikit-learn 0.24.0 with pip then anaconda (Windows 10). I also have Pandas NumPy and SciPy,
and when I type pip list all of the packages are on there. However when I open VSCode and run "from sklearn import tree" with Python 3.3, 3.75, or 3.91 the output is "Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'sklearn'"

Comment: So it seems like you have different versions of python on your system, which is already a red flag. I would recommend uninstalling all of them and reinstalling whichever one you want and install scikit learn again

Comment: I would not recommend uninstalling Python installs.  You can have other stuff involved that makes use of those installs, and will break if you uninstall them. Multiple Python versions on a machine is not a problem as long as you know how to switch between them with all your various tools.

Comment: I agree with @F.M that you are likely installing packages into one version of Python and running with another.  That is almost always what is going on in these kinds of cases.  Make sure that you know exactly which Python executable you are running with, and insure that the `pip` you are running via VSCode is coming from the same directory.  You might look to see if you can get a list of modules from VSCode such that you're sure you're seeing the module list for the same version of Python that you're executing with.

Comment: @Steve Thanks a lot for the help it works now, if anyone else has a similar problem do python(your version here, example:3.9) -m pip install (package name here, example: scikit-learn)